# What is this item used for?

Tags: hygiene

What is the following item use for?

I got it with a nail polisher, and bunch of other hygiene items. Here's what was included:

- one nail file
- two nail clippers
- ear cleaner
- cotton pliers
- small scissors

The white section is rough.

[image]

Comment: Off-topic, really? I'm in a foreign country and get a bunch of utensils for a meal. If I don't recognize one, I might want to know what it should be used for. If we've had questions on using various types of toilets, why wouldn't a hygiene device be on-topic?

Comment: OP, is the white section smooth or rough? Is it symmetric? That is, there's not a scoop or hollow on the other side? My first thoughts were some sort of ear cleaning device or nail file. Where did you receive it and what's the full list of items in the packet.

Comment: The white section is rough. I got it with one nail file, two nail clipper, ear cleaner, cotton pliers,.and a small scissor.

Comment: What are "cotton pliers?"

Comment: Under what circumstances did you receive this kit? On an airplane or boat? At a nail salon? In a café with your coffee?

Comment: I upvoted David's comment.  If this set is somehow connected with travel, the question should reflect that.  If not, it is probably off topic.

Comment: It's a rubber tipped cuticle pusher. Used for pushing back your nail cuticles.

Comment: cosmetology.stackexchange.com where are you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's probably an **emery stone** or **pumice stone** (or something similar) on a stick.

When small and pointed like this, they're usually used in manicures or pedicures to remove cuticles and other build-ups of dead skin.

Here's a similar example with a pumice stone: https://www.idobeauty4u.co.uk/pumice-stone-cuticle-hoof-stick-nail-file-grit-nail-tool-manicure-pedicure-files-2483-p.asp

[image]

Here's one with an emery stone (the white part - the hexagonal part fits into a machine): https://www.ebay.com/itm/Nail-Genie-Manicuring-Attachments-Pointed-Emery-Stone-/323778888878

[image]